# What causes ssh to return Network is down?

Tags: macos, terminal, unix, ssh

I'm trying, without success, connect to a local network ssh server from macOS by doing:

```
$ ssh user@1111:ab1:123:ab1:011b:12bc:ab12:1a2b
```

and then I get:

```
ssh: connect to host 1111:ab1:123:ab1:011b:12bc:ab12:1a2b port 22: Network is down
```

I actually can connect to that server from iPhone app Termius (and there are also other reasons to think the server side is ok) so I believe there is a problem on the client side. I tried that same app on macOS without success.

Also, ssh to a virtual machine works well, as well as to an amazon aws server.

Also tried verbose:

```
$ ssh user@1111:ab1:123:ab1:011b:12bc:ab12:1a2b -vvv
OpenSSH_7.6p1, LibreSSL 2.6.2
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 48: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 1111:ab1:123:ab1:011b:12bc:ab12:1a2b port 22.
ssh: connect to host 1111:ab1:123:ab1:011b:12bc:ab12:1a2b port 22: Network is down
```

And IPV6:

```
$ ssh -6 -vvv user@1111:ab1:123:ab1:011b:12bc:ab12:1a2b
OpenSSH_7.6p1, LibreSSL 2.6.2
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 48: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 1111:ab1:123:ab1:011b:12bc:ab12:1a2b port 22.
ssh: connect to host 1111:ab1:123:ab1:011b:12bc:ab12:1a2b port 22: Network is down
```

And ping:

```
$ ping 1111:ab1:123:ab1:011b:12bc:ab12:1a2b
ping: cannot resolve 1111:ab1:123:ab1:011b:12bc:ab12:1a2b: Unknown host
```

What might be causing the `Network is down`? How should I debug this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SSH is just the messenger, and is likely calling `strerror(3)` or equivalent on a bad exit code from some socket call:

```
$ find /usr/include -name "*.h" -exec grep 'Network is down' {} +
/usr/include/apr-1/apr_errno.h:#define SOCENETDOWN             (SOCBASEERR+50)            /* Network is down */
/usr/include/sys/errno.h:#define        ENETDOWN        50              /* Network is down */
$
```

If we dig around in the system man pages for `ENETDOWN` this will turn up documentation...

```
$ find /usr/share/man -type f -exec grep -l ENETDOWN {} +
/usr/share/man/man2/connect.2
/usr/share/man/man2/connectx.2
/usr/share/man/man2/intro.2
/usr/share/man/man2/send.2
...
```

Though not much as `connect(2)` or `intro(2)` merely indicate

```
 [ENETDOWN]         The local network interface is not functioning.
...
 50 ENETDOWN Network is down.  A socket operation encountered a dead net-
         work.
```

Is IPv6 working on this host? You'll probably need to debug with `ping6` (not `ping`) and maybe check the IPv6 settings via some clicky interface or instead `ifconfig` and `netstat -rn`.

To avoid the GUI, the network settings for IPv6 can be adjusted with something like

```
sudo ipconfig set en0 AUTOMATIC-V6
```

see the `ipconfig(8)` manual for details.

Comment: `ping6: UDP connect: No route to host`

Comment: Got it. IPV6 was `Off` in `System Preferences`>`Network`>`Advanced`>`TCP/IP`. Changed to `auto` and solved!